# Can you provide your own KeyManagementService implementation in Corda (e.g. using a HSM)?

Tags: corda

I would like to provide my own HSM-based implementation for the `KeyManagementService` interface in Corda.

How can I get the Corda node to use my `KeyManagementService` implementation, instead of the default implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corda is designed to support HSMs for key management. Currently, the doorman integrates with HSMs, and there will be built-in node support for various HSMs in R3 Corda in the future.

However, as of Corda V3, it is not possible to inject user-defined services into the node.